# Assigning Value to attribute of struct

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I am trying to assign value to the attributes of a pointer to a struct, but get Segmentation Faults.

```
  typedef struct {
    int id;
    char payload[10];
  }packet;

  void main(){
   packet *header;
   header->id = 1;
  }
```

It compiles but it gives me a seg fault when I run it. It only works when I use "malloc" when creating header. Why is that? Normally I don't have to allocate memory for other pointer types.

Comment: Please remember that the correct return type for `main()` is `int`, not `void`, despite what you can read in numerous books. Also, none of the answers below suggesting the use of `malloc()` actually bothers to check that `malloc()` succeeded.  Granted, in the scope of this program, failure is extremely improbable.  However, good practices remain good practices, and not checking `malloc()` will eventually bite you — probably when your program is being demo'd to the CEO or has been released to thousands if not millions of customers, with consequential costs to fixing the problem.

Comment: If you see `void main()` in a book, that's a sign that the author doesn't know C very well and that you should find a better book. (`void main()`, or better `void main(void)`, might be correct for an embedded system, but if you're working on such a system you should already know that.)

Answer (score 3):

In this case, header is not being initialised - it is a pointer so that means that is is not pointing to anything meaningful. When you try to assign a value to header->id you get a segfault. This is perfectly logical, and it is right to only work when you have malloced memory for it.

Either, you want to create an actual packet:

```
packet header;
header.id = 1;
```

or you want to heap allocate one:

```
packet* header = malloc(sizeof(packet));
if(header){ //Check if malloc succeeded
    header->id = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two things:

```
packet *header = (packet*) malloc (sizeof (packet));
```

or

```
packet header;
header.id = 10;
```

Depending on your use case, one may be more suitable than the other.  If you are going to use `malloc`, remember to call `free` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "Normally I don't have to allocate memory for other pointer types", either the pointer is a primitive type (like an int), or the struct is already allocated some memory (probably from the stack).

So this should work without malloc:

```
int main() {
   packet headerOnStack;
   packet *header = &headerOnStack;
   header->id = 1;
}
```

However, because it is on stack, once `main()` returns, the struct will be gone.  Normally, this isn't an issue, because once `main()` returns, your program is done.  If this was another function though, then this would be a factor that you have to consider.

Comment: If you're going to post a suggested fix, please change the incorrect `void main()` to the correct `int main(void)`. (Conceivably `void main()` could be correct for an embedded system, but it's not likely the OP is working with such a system.)

Answer (score 0):

The fault here lies that you do not initialize the pointer, which will because of that,  point to nothing, trying to access an attribute of the pointers location which is still 'nothing' will lead to a seg fault